# Positioning labels and color coding in sunburst - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This is what is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHl0R.jpg)I have a data set which contains unit, weight of each unit and compliance score for each unit in year 2016. 
[I was not able to add the table but here is the screenshot for the data in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hESHp.png)

I have named the columns in the data as unit, weight and year(which is compliance score) .

I want to create a sunburst chart where the first ring will be the unit divided based on weight and the second ring will be the same but will have labels compliance score.

The colour for each ring will be different.

I was able to do some code with the help from an online blog and the output I have gotten is similar to what I want but I am facing difficulty in positioning of the labels and also the colour coding for each ring

```
#using ggplot
library(ggplot2) # Visualisation
library(dplyr) # data wrangling
library(scales) # formatting

#read file
weight.eg = read.csv("Dummy Data.csv", header = FALSE, sep = 
";",encoding = "UTF-8") 

#change column names
colnames(weight.eg) <- c ("unit","weight","year")

#as weight column is factor change into integer
weight.eg$weight = as.numeric(levels(weight.eg$weight)) 
[as.integer(weight.eg$weight)]
weight.eg$year = as.numeric(levels(weight.eg$year)) 
[as.integer(weight.eg$year)]
#Nas are introduced, remove
weight.eg <- na.omit(weight.eg)

#Sum of the total weight
sum_total_weight = sum(weight.eg$weight)

#First layer
firstLevel = weight.eg %>% summarize(total_weight=sum(weight))
sunburst_0 = ggplot(firstLevel) # Just a foundation

#this will generate a bar chart 
sunburst_1 = 
sunburst_0 + 
geom_bar(data=firstLevel, aes(x=1, y=total_weight), 
fill='darkgrey', stat='identity') +
geom_text(aes(x=1, y=sum_total_weight/2, label=paste("Total 
Weight", comma(total_weight))), color='black')
#View  
sunburst_1
#this argument is used to rotate the plot around the y-axis which 
the total weight 
sunburst_1 + coord_polar(theta = "y")

sunburst_2=
sunburst_1 +
geom_bar(data=weight.eg,
       aes(x=2, y=weight.eg$weight, fill=weight.eg$weight),
       color='white', position='stack', stat='identity', size=0.6) 
+ 
geom_text(data=weight.eg, aes(label=paste(weight.eg$unit, 
weight.eg$weight), x=2, y=weight.eg$weight), position='stack')

sunburst_2 + coord_polar(theta = "y") 

sunburst_3 =
sunburst_2 +
geom_bar(data=weight.eg,
       aes(x=3, y=weight.eg$weight,fill=weight.eg$weight),
       color='white', position='stack', stat='identity', 
size=0.6)+
geom_text(data = weight.eg, 
aes(label=paste(weight.eg$year),x=3,y=weight.eg$weight),position = 
'stack')  


sunburst_3 + coord_polar(theta = "y") 

sunburst_3 + scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) + 
scale_fill_continuous(low='white', high='darkred') + 
coord_polar('y') + theme_minimal()

Output for dput(weight.eg)
structure(list(unit = structure(2:7, .Label = c("", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "Unit"), class = "factor"), weight = c(30, 
25, 10, 17, 5, 13), year = c(70, 80, 50, 30, 60, 40)), .Names = 
c("unit", 
"weight", "year"), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame", na.action 
= structure(c(1L, 
8L), .Names = c("1", "8"), class = "omit"))

output for dput(firstLevel)
structure(list(total_weight = 100), .Names = "total_weight", row.names 
= c(NA, 
-1L), na.action = structure(c(1L, 8L), .Names = c("1", "8"), class = 
"omit"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry. Its hard to help as we don't have your data nor do we know what your plot looks like -- and have only a vague idea of your problem with said plot. Best give a small chunk of data, a shorter summarised chunk of code, a pic and pointer to the problem?

Comment: @StephenHenderson Hi, I have added the pic of the output. I was not able to add the table so have added the screenshot. It will be great if you could help. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(weight.eg)` and `dput(firstLevel)` so that we could attempt to reproduce your plotting process and see how we can help?

Comment: @teunbrand i have added the output at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I might have some sort of solution for you. I wasn't sure what you wanted to color-code on the outer ring; from your code it seems you wanted it to be the weight again, but it was not obvious to me. For different colour scales per ring, you could use the ggnewscale package:

```
library(ggnewscale)
```

For the centering of the labels you could write a function:

```
cs_fun <- function(x){(cumsum(x) + c(0, cumsum(head(x , -1))))/ 2}
```

Now the plotting code could look something like this:

```
ggplot(weight.eg) +
  # Note: geom_col is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_col(data = firstLevel,
           aes(x = 1, y = total_weight)) +
  geom_text(data = firstLevel,
            aes(x = 1, y = total_weight / 2, 
                label = paste("Total Weight:", total_weight)),
            colour = "black") +
  geom_col(aes(x = 2, 
               y = weight, fill = weight),
           colour = "white", size = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Weight", 
                      low = "white", high = "darkred") +
  # Open up new fill scale for next ring
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = cs_fun(weight), 
                label = paste(unit, weight))) +
  geom_col(aes(x = 3, y = weight, fill = weight), 
           size = 0.6, colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Another Weight?", 
                      low = "forestgreen", high = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(year), x = 3, 
                y = cs_fun(weight))) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: the outer layer is the year. Thank you so much for the solution. but when i am running the code it is saying Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : could not find function "isFALSE". Do you know what could be the problem

Comment: i tried searching online about the meaning of this error, but i didn't get. Can you tell what could be solution for the error

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, can you figure out which part of the code is causing the error?

Comment: # Open up new fill scale for next ring
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = cs_fun(weight), 
                label = paste(unit, weight))) +
  geom_col(aes(x = 3, y = weight, fill = weight), 
           size = 0.6, colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Another Weight?", 
                      low = "forestgreen", high = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(year), x = 3, 
                y = cs_fun(weight))) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")

Comment: This part. because the above part is giving the output properly

Comment: Does omitting the `new_scale_fill()` produce a viable plot? If yes, have you correctly installed the ggnewscale package? I'm running R3.6.1 and ggplot 3.2.0 and ggnewscale 0.2.0, so maybe it could be a version issue?

Comment: if i remove new_scale_fill(), the colours are forest green only. the dark red colour does not appear. My R version is pretty old but ggnewscale is 0.3.0and ggplot is 3.2.0

Comment: new_scale_fill() and even if i get the output it is giving this warning:               
 Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.

Comment: Yes that warning message makes sense and is what I would have expected if you remove the new_scale_fill(). So that seems to be the problematic function, I'll have a look around the ggnewscale github to see if I could find what might cause the error.

Comment: Apparently this is an issue with versions of R < 3.5 (see https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale/issues/12), but according to the package news (https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale/blob/master/NEWS.md) this should have been fixed for ggnewscale 0.4.0.9

Comment: got it. will try to do this problem with R newer versions

Comment: That would work, however if you're attached to your R version for some reason, you could also download the 0.4.0 of ggnewscale from the github page instead of from CRAN.

Comment: I want to add another layer and have added column in the data. If I follow the same code. It is giving me this error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NewGeomCol' not found". The output for dput(weight.eg) is structure(list(unit = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "Unit"), class = "factor"), weight = c(30, 25, 
10, 17, 5, 13), year16 = c(70, 80, 50, 30, 60, 40), year17 = c(50, 
100, 20, 30, 70, 60)), .Names = c("unit", "weight", "year16", 
"year17"), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(1L, .Names = "1", class = "omit"))

Comment: I have no problem expanding the plot with a 3rd layer, do you know what piece of code is causing the error?

Comment: there is a problem in the last layer itself. I wrote this code:        new_scale_fill()+
  geom_text(aes(x = 3, y = cs_fun(weight), 
                label = paste(weight, year16)))
  geom_col(aes(x = 4, y = year17, fill = year17),
           size = 0.6, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "year17",
                      low = "red", high = "green")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(unit,year17), x = 4,
                y = cs_fun(weight)))

Comment: After adding a `+` before the geom_col I could get a plot without errors. It looks a bit wierd, but I don't get the error you mentioned.

Comment: even if i add + still same error. Is my code right? or is it something else

Comment: I think the error is when adding the third ring. Is the code which i mentioned correct? I tried again but no such luck. this is like the final step then my assignment will be done. Can you please help.